# Uglify directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

Rather than adding code and files to the uglify script individually, is there any way to tell uglify to grab an entire dir, and output into 1 script.js file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cat * | uglifyjs -o script.js
```

If by uglifyjs you mean https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS this works! Without an input file `uglifyjs` will read from `STDIN`.

Comment: I had appended a `w` to the link

Comment: 1. You `cd` into the dir with all you script files 2. You run `cat * | uglifyjs -o script.js` 3. You're done

Comment: Is there an easy modification of this that will also recursively traverse subdirectories?

Comment: @UpTheCreek, see mishoo's answer below.  A slightly different variation on the find command will do what you want.

Comment: Wish this could be updated to provide a `file.min.js` file for each source file

Comment: @balupton: `for f in *; do uglifyjs -o \`echo $f | sed 's/\.js$/.min.js/'\` $f; done`

Comment: If you're running this on Windows the command is `type * | uglifyjs -o script.js`

Answer (score 10):

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*.js" | xargs cat | uglifyjs -o > result.js
```

Note that the load order of your scripts might be important.  The above could therefore fail (as it just dumps the files in whatever order `find` happens to return them).  I would suggest you to write a small shell script customized for your application.

Comment: This will generate an error. You need to remove the redirect ">" for it to work

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uglifyjs-folder` module for that. It also supports processing them individually (no merging together).

https://github.com/ionutvmi/uglifyjs-folder
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/balupton/buildr.npm may also be helpful

> The (Java|Coffee)Script and (CSS|Less) (Builder|Bundler|Packer|Minifier|Merger|Checker)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I found [Igneous](https://npmjs.org/package/igneous) to be very convenient. It does what it says without imposing additional constraints or philosphies.